# ASP.Net Web API call resulting in an HTTP 404 - "/Home/" being inserted in API call?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Please, bear with me, as I'm still fairly new to working with the ASP.Net Web API.

I currently have an API that I have developed, and it seems to be working fine.  I am able to call it using AJAX from my main page, and everything works as expected.  So for example, I am able to make a call like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/comment/AddComment",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //and so on...
});
```

And this works just fine when calling it from my Index page, when the URL looks like localhost:44966/

I'm now at the point where I need to start adding some functionality to some of the other views - in particular a view for users to add feedback to the site.  I added a new view on my HomeController that displays the new Feedback view, as well as a new ApiController (called FeedbackController).  On that page, I try making a call like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/Feedback/SubmitFeedback",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success!");
    }
});
```

This results in a 404, and looking at the URL in the call, it's no wonder that it's failing, as it looks like this:

```
    /Home/api/Feedback/SubmitFeedback
```

I've also noticed that if I navigate back home (this time to localhost:44966/Home/Index), my other service calls also fail with similar 404 responses because of that same problem - it seems to be inserting a "/Home/" before all of the URLs that it is trying to use to access the API.

Can someone shed some light on what is going on here?  Why is "/Home/" being inserted in before the name of the API call?

Before anyone asks, here's what my WebApiConfig routing looks like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax request is taking the relative path in order to make the call. You have to provide a full path to your api.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/full/path/to/api/comment/AddComment",
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/comment/AddComment",
```

If your api is hosted on your server's root.

Comment: Is there some way of specifying "hey, this is relative to root" without having to manually specify the whole path, like by using a tilde (e.g.: "~/api/Comment/AddComment")?

Comment: It would seem that adding a beginning slash seems to make it work from the root. e.g.:  "/api/Feedback/SubmitComment" seems to work, at least when on the feedback page.  When I navigate back to localhost:44966/Home/Index, the other api calls still seem to choke.  Is this because the way my default routing is set up?